# How to safely stop a thread launched from an alertdialog?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

When I show an alertdialog, I start a thread that starts a 30 second countdown to update a determinate progressbar shown in this alertdialog.

I create the runnable as a static inner class so that I don't leak the context(activity), but then of course I can't access the flag to stop the thread, nor the views I want to update.  How can I get around this?

```
public class MyDialogFragment implements DialogInterface.onShowListener, DialogInterface.onDismissListener {

private boolean stopThread = false;
private Progressbar countdownBar;
private TextView countdownRatio;

@Override public void onShow() { 
    Thread progressThread = new Thread(new myRunnable());
    progressThread.start();
}

@Override public void onDismiss() {
    stopThread = true;
    this.dismiss();
}

private static class myRunnable implements Runnable {

    int progressStatus = 0;
    int numSeconds = 30;

    @Override public void run() {
        while (!threadStop && progressStatus < numSeconds) {
            progressStatus++;

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    countdownBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    countdownRatio.setText(progressStatus + "/" + numSeconds + " secs");
                }
            });
            try {
                // update the counter every sec
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to pass an instance of the Activity in order to call the runOnUiThread() method. I see no other way to update UI apart from setting a broadcastreceiver and pass info with the intent or maybe call static methods from the main activity

Answer (score 1):

First - don't use `Thread` - you're asking for troubles, especially that you don't seem to be comfortable with multi-threaded programming. It's a tricky topic with tons of pitfalls. It's definitely not for noobs.

You may use `AsyncTask` for this - it has nice integration with UI event loop via `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate()`. `AsyncTask` uses internal thread pool.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

`AsyncTask` is ok for most trivial stuff. For more advanced uses try using `Service` with worker threads and message bus to communicate with fragments or activities. There is plenty of libraries for asynchronous programming. I can recommend this one:

https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice

It's main purpose if networking, but you can use it for other stuff as well.

Third solution is `Loader` API:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html

It's intended for asynchronous loading of data from database (SQLite is slow), but it's quite easy to use it for other stuff, such as data processing.

Remember: if you use `Thread`, there are 2 possibilities:

1. You are expert and you know what you're doing
2. You are green and you're doing it wrong